# Looking for Android Apps made on Sencha Touch wrapped by PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I am a WEB/Mobile developer and I would like to try/test the UI performance of an application done in **Sencha Touch wrapped by PhoneGap**, does any one have a list of apps or maybe known of anyone that I can install in my HTC EVO?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Travelmate comes in three flavors - Android (phonegap), iOS (phonegap) and plain web: jag.gr/tm. It's Sencha Touch 1.0 all the way. Just as a reminder - Touch 2, now in preview, has a much better Android scroller. [I'm at Sencha]